# AudioKit and Bass MIDI player

Tags: ios, audiokit, bass

We are considering using the [AudioKit](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit) framework along with the BASSMIDI sampler provided by http://www.un4seen.com/ in our iOS app.

Here is what we aim to implement :

- Play a MIDI File using the AudioKit sequencer
- Send the MIDI events (read by the AudioKit sequencer) to the BASSMIDI sampler.
- Redirect the BASSMIDI sampler's audio output to an AudioKit Mixer instance

Our main concern is that it doesn't seem possible to access the BASSMIDI sampler's audio output.

Has anyone had the experience to do this ?
Is it simply possible ?

Thanks in advance for your insights!

Answer (score 0):

For those who would be interested in using the BASSMIDI player on iOS, we finally ended up implementing an AUv3 Audio Unit wrapped around the bassmidi library.

The main advantage is that this audio unit can be inserted into a graph of audio nodes handled by the iOS Audio Engine (just like you would do with the `AVAudioUnitSampler`).

The code is available on a public repository:
https://github.com/newzik/BassMidiAudioUnit

Feel free to use it!